# Show that a sequence is weakly convergent to $0$ in $\ell^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that a sequence $(f_n)=2009e_n+e_{2010n}$ is weakly convergent to $0$ in $\ell_{2}$ where $e_n$ are standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that I should use Riesz representation theorem, but I can't see how $(f_n)$ is in $\ell^{2}$

Comment: That seems confused. Are your vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for different $n$? Or are the $e_n$ supposed to be the standard basis vectors in $\ell^2$? Assuming the latter, $f_n$ belongs trivially to $\ell^2$, because it has only two non-zero terms. And the sequence $(f_n)$ is not a member of $\ell^2$; it is just a sequence of members of $\ell^2$.

Comment: Sorry. $e_n$ are just vectors that have $1$ as nth term and 0 everywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $\ell^2$ consists of tuples $(a_1, a_2, \ldots )$ such that $\sum a_i^2 < \infty$. Your $f_n$ have the property that $||f_n||^2 = (2009)^2 + 1 < \infty$, so they are in $\ell^2$.

As for them converging weakly to zero, by definition this is the case if

$$\langle f_n, g \rangle \rightarrow 0 $$

for all $g = (a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ in $\ell^2$. But $\langle f_n, g \rangle = 2009 a_n + a_{2010n}$, which converges to zero by the summability of the series $\sum a_i^2$.

Comment: I know, but I can't see how $||f_n||^2 = (2009)^2 + 1 < \infty $

Comment: and do $f_n$ converges in norm?

Comment: Seriously? You can't see that $(2009)^2+1<\infty$? Does it help to compute the number? Its value is $4036082$. That's a small number, compared to some governments' budget deficits.

Comment: I mean why $||f_n||^2 = (2009)^2 + 1$... why so nervous...

Comment: No, it doesn't converge in norm. Since it goes weakly to zero, any norm limit would have to be zero too, but as the norm is constant, it does not go to zero.

Comment: Ah, oh, that. $f_n$ has only two nonzero terms. One is the $n$th term, which is $2009$, and the other is the $2010n$th term, which is $1$. Square each, add them together, then add an infinite number of zeros for the remaining terms. The extra amounts to nothing, of course.

Comment: ohh sorry, I'm so stupid. I see what you mean now. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It helps to slow down, sometimes.

Comment: yeah, $f_n$ is a sequence of members of $\ell^{2}$ as you said in first comment. and I made a mistake thinking that $f_n$ itself must be in $\ell^2$...

Comment: Actually no, each $f_n$ IS itself in $\ell^2$. Elements of $\ell^2$ are (infinite) sequences of numbers. The size of such an infinite sequence is the sum of the squares of its terms. If it helps, think about $\mathbb{R}^n$: an element is $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ so its size is $a_1^2+ \ldots + a_n^2$. The space $\ell^2$ is basically what this, but $n = \infty$.